# Exercise of interior of a closed ball

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $E$ a normed spaces and $a\in E$. How to prove that $$[\overline{B}(a, r)]^{\circ}\subseteq B(a, r)$$ where $\overline{B}(a, r)=\{x\in E: \|x-a\|\leq r\}$ and  $B(a, r)=\{x\in E: \|x-a\|< r\}$

Comment: I made a test of the year but got too complicated too and I think that exercise can go easier. I appreciate your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can assume $a=0$. Let $x \in \text{int} \, \overline{B}(0,r)$ and $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta) \subseteq \overline{B}(0,r)$. For $y :=t \cdot x$, $t>1$ we have $$y \in B(x,\delta) \Leftrightarrow \|\underbrace{y}_{t \cdot x}-x\|<\delta \Leftrightarrow \|x\| \cdot (t-1)< \delta$$ i.e. we can choose $t>1$ such that $t \cdot x \in B(x,\delta) \subseteq \overline{B}(0,r)$. This implies $\|t \cdot x\| \leq r$ and so (since $t>1$) we conclude $$\|x\| \leq \frac{r}{t} < r.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be an interior element of the closed ball. Then there is some $\delta > 0$ so that $B(x, \delta)$ lies in the closed ball.  Every element of $B(x, \delta)$ lies in the open ball. You can use the triangle inequality to see this.

Comment: With triangle inequality ncmathsadist? How would you?